# Directly Update Doc Template from Form

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to submit a form and update a Doc template from the form contents? The only way I have seen for doing anything similar was submitting the form to a spreadsheet and having an onFormsubmit function within the spreadsheet update the template.

Is this not possible via forms and a container bound script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have initially gotten this to work replacing a few lines in my document template, but now nothing is working for some reason. I did edit the text in the template at one point so I am not sure if that changes the file ID. It creates the copy, but the replaceText is not working. Code attached:

```
`function onFormSubmit(e) {

   var dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', "MM/dd/yyyy")
   var submitter = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var copyDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1t5r8IxLgunJ17J2tXkHfw3LRfuXQeTlP5MZURC-23e0').makeCopy('tmpAddress').getId();
   var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyDoc);
   var body = newDoc.getBody();

   var itemResponse = e.response;
   var name = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
   var email = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
   var pphone = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
   var paddress = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();
   var palot = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[4].getResponse();
   var pcity = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[5].getResponse();
   var pstate = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[6].getResponse();
   var pzip = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[7].getResponse();
   var nphone = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[8].getResponse();
   var naddress = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[9].getResponse();
   var nalot = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[10].getResponse();
   var ncity = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[11].getResponse();
   var nstate = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[12].getResponse();
   var nzip = itemResponse.getItemResponses()[13].getResponse();

   body.replaceText('#{name}', name);
   body.replaceText('#{email}', email);
   body.replaceText('#{pphone}', pphone);
   body.replaceText('#{paddress}', paddress);
   body.replaceText('#{palot}', palot);
   body.replaceText('#{pcity}', pcity);
   body.replaceText('#{pstate}', pstate);
   body.replaceText('#{pzip}', pzip);
   body.replaceText('#{nphone}', nphone);
   body.replaceText('#{naddress}', naddress);
   body.replaceText('#{nalot}', nalot);
   body.replaceText('#{ncity}', ncity);
   body.replaceText('#{nstate}', nstate);
   body.replaceText('#{nzip}', nzip);
   body.replaceText('#{dt}', dt)
   body.replaceText('#{submitter}',submitter)
   newDoc.saveAndClose();

 }
`
```

Comment: The execution transcript states: Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method "getItemResponses" of undefined. (line 10, file "Code")

Comment: Deleted the trigger and added again and the process works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible, but it's not easy (essentially using doc as template, there is no evident tools for that)

Comment: If I can find out how to read the form contents into an array the rest would be cake.

Comment: @Rocknyou'll find that here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit